# $.each showing only first value of json and other values are shown as undefined in ajax success.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

hi guys i am trying to get the value of json arrays in $.each and get there values passed to another ajax the value is being sent from controller to view but can't show the values using $.each function. let me show you my code to explain what is the problem

```
    function getfriend_requests()
    {
    var id=$('.id_data').attr('value');

    jQuery.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'<?php echo base_url("user/getallfriends"); ?>',
                    data:{id:id},
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data)
                    {   
                        console.log(data);
                            var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
                        var friend_request_data= $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

                          $.each(friend_request_data, function(key,data) 
                            {

                              var uname=data.uname;
                              var senders_id=data.senders_id;
                               alert(senders_id);
                              var recievers_id=data.recievers_id;
                              var request_status=data.request_status;
                               alert(recievers_id);
                               alert(uname);
                              jQuery.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url:'<?php  echo base_url("user/get_friends_Data"); ?>',
                            data:{senders_id:senders_id,recievers_id:recievers_id},
                            dataType:'json',
                            success:function(data)
                            {
                                   console.log(data); 
                                    var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
                                     var sender_values = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);
                                // var senders_name=sender_values.sender_data;
                                // alert(senders_name);
                                var id=$('.id_data').attr('value');
                                    $.each(sender_values, function(key,data) 
                       {
                        var uname = data.uname;
                        var senders_id=data.id;

                        alert(uname);
                        alert(senders_id);
                        // $('.senders_div').attr('senders_id', $senders_id);
                        // if(senders_id==id)
                        // {

                        // }
                        // else{
                        //    if(uname){  
                        //     alert(request_status);
                        //     if(request_status=='pending')
                        //     {
                        //       //alert('hello');
                        //     }else{
                        //       //alert('data');
                        //     }

                            $('.friends_sidebar').append('<div>'+uname +'</div>');




                         });
                            //       $.each(sender_values,function,(key,data)
                            //       {
                            //         var uname = data.uname;
                            //          if(uname){  
                            // $('.friends_sidebar').html('<div>'+uname +'has sent you a request</div>');

                            //  }
                            //       });
                              }
                        });
                            });
                    }
                });
    }

now in this code when i try to use 'friend_request_data' it shows undefined alerting values all shows undefined. so i cant send the values to the second ajax that i am using 
let me also show you the controller 

        public function getallfriends()
    {
      $id=$this->input->post('id');
      $this->load->model('Pmodel');
      $data['senders']=$this->Pmodel->get_all_user_friends_sender($id);


      $data['recievers']=$this->Pmodel->get_all_user_friends_reciever($id);

      echo json_encode($data);
    }
    public function get_friends_Data()
    {
       $senders_id=$this->input->post('senders_id');
       $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $recievers_id=$this->input->post('recievers_id');
        $this->load->model('Pmodel');

    if($user_id==$senders_id)
    {

    }else{
      $userdata['senders_data']=$this->Pmodel->getUserdata($senders_id);

    }

    if($user_id==$recievers_id)
    {

    }
    else{
      $userdata['recievers_data']=$this->Pmodel->getUserdata($recievers_id);
    }

    echo json_encode($userdata);
    }
    }
```

this code works completly as the echo json_encode($userdata) all values are being shown in the firebug console. let me show you some image to understand better.

[image: ajax showing null value]
[image: get_all_friends]
[image: ajax second function]

can you please tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: Can you explain this part? `var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data); var friend_request_data= $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);` If you have to stringify, then reparse again, something seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `$each` to iterate over the data?

You can use a simple `for`-loop instead, so that `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` can be removed

Comment: If i dont parse the value it will only show me undefined or object object.

Comment: I think the problem might be ralted to query since when i return $query->result_array it shows undefined otherwise if i use $query->row_array it return a single row not the whole array @DagosPodaru's

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.